# ActionCable on subdomain instead of subdir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I am trying to get ActionCable work on a subdomain.

the problem is that as soon as I am changing the following line

```
config.action_cable.mount_path = '/'
```

The app isn't working anymore. But ActionCable works on a subdomain. Is there any solution to run ActionCable on a subdomain without a subdir like `/cable`?

Comment: I also want this problem answer

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you'll need to run it as a standalone server if you're not using an in-app server with a sub-uri:  https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable#consumer-configuration

You can specify the cable url like so:

```
config.action_cable.url = 'ws://cable.example.com:28080'
```

> The cable server(s) is separated from your normal application server. It's still a Rack application, but it is its own Rack application. The recommended basic setup is as follows:

```
# cable/config.ru
require_relative '../config/environment'
Rails.application.eager_load!

run ActionCable.server
```

> Then you start the server using a binstub in bin/cable ala:

```
#!/bin/bash
bundle exec puma -p 28080 cable/config.ru
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/actioncable#standalone

Comment: It depends on how you configure the cable server. I've added that info to the answer

Comment: "It looks like you'll need to run it as a standalone server if you're not using an in-app server with a sub-uri" 

The link you mentioned doesn't seem to work anymore. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @LuisVasconcellos Looks like it moved here: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#running-standalone-cable-servers